# Strange JSON-like data format in CSV

Tags: json, csv, yaml

I have to work with a strange JSON-like format that crashes parsers because it is not quite JSON (no quotes, equals sign instead of colon etc).

Has anyone seen a data format like this and if so what is it?

```
"[{location_type=1, location_fullname=Papua New Guinea, location_countrycode=PP, location_adm1code=PP, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=147, location_featureid=PP, character_offset=16},..."
```

It is nested inside a CSV structure so I am wondering if it is related to that.

**Edit**:

Full example

```
[{location_type=1, location_fullname=Papua New Guinea, location_countrycode=PP, location_adm1code=PP, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=147, location_featureid=PP, character_offset=16}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=Papua New Guinea, location_countrycode=PP, location_adm1code=PP, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=147, location_featureid=PP, character_offset=290}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=Indonesia, location_countrycode=ID, location_adm1code=ID, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-5, location_longitude=120, location_featureid=ID, character_offset=676}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=North Korea, location_countrycode=KN, location_adm1code=KN, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=40, location_longitude=127, location_featureid=KN, character_offset=748}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=British Indian Ocean Territory, location_countrycode=IO, location_adm1code=IO, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=71.5, location_featureid=IO, character_offset=892}]
```

Running this through as yaml with python gives the following:

```
import yaml
dct = yaml.safe_load(body)
dct
[{'location_type=1': None,
  'location_fullname=Papua New Guinea': None,
  'location_countrycode=PP': None,
...
```

Comment: It is YAML. Try pasting bits into [HERE](http://www.yamllint.com). Read about it [HERE](https://yaml.org). JSON is a dependent of YAML btw.

Comment: @dawg I tried running this through a yaml parser and the results were incorrect too- any preprocessing required beforehand?

Comment: Show a bigger example. The bit you have does validate... And what environment?

Comment: @micah5 Do you want to convert it to JSON?

Comment: @dawg I am using python3.9, I have attached a full example to the post edit with the error (see the incorrect keys)

Comment: @Fravadona yes that would be perfect- or any way that I can parse it into a python dict

Comment: @micah5 I updated my answer, take a look at it ;-)

Comment: @Fravadona Thank you! Both answers work, wish I could accept them both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format seems compatible enough for converting it to YAML or JSON with just a few string manipulations.

###### 1. YAML conversion

That is the simplest way to load your string into a list of dictionaries. If your Python project already requires YAML then you don't have any reason to not use this solution:

```py
import yaml

body = '[{location_type=1, location_fullname=Papua New Guinea, location_countrycode=PP, location_adm1code=PP, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=147, location_featureid=PP, character_offset=16}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=Papua New Guinea, location_countrycode=PP, location_adm1code=PP, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=147, location_featureid=PP, character_offset=290}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=Indonesia, location_countrycode=ID, location_adm1code=ID, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-5, location_longitude=120, location_featureid=ID, character_offset=676}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=North Korea, location_countrycode=KN, location_adm1code=KN, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=40, location_longitude=127, location_featureid=KN, character_offset=748}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=British Indian Ocean Territory, location_countrycode=IO, location_adm1code=IO, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=71.5, location_featureid=IO, character_offset=892}]'

dct = yaml.safe_load( body.replace('=',': ') )
```

---

###### 2. JSON conversion

You can use this solution if you prefer to avoid adding an external dependency (YAML) to your project. While most people don't care about that, I do care (the less the best). The caveat is that it requires knowing the data structure for converting the data types (the function is a slightly modified version of @dawg [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71515783/3387716)):

```py
import re
import json

body = '[{location_type=1, location_fullname=Papua New Guinea, location_countrycode=PP, location_adm1code=PP, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=147, location_featureid=PP, character_offset=16}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=Papua New Guinea, location_countrycode=PP, location_adm1code=PP, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=147, location_featureid=PP, character_offset=290}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=Indonesia, location_countrycode=ID, location_adm1code=ID, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-5, location_longitude=120, location_featureid=ID, character_offset=676}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=North Korea, location_countrycode=KN, location_adm1code=KN, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=40, location_longitude=127, location_featureid=KN, character_offset=748}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=British Indian Ocean Territory, location_countrycode=IO, location_adm1code=IO, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=71.5, location_featureid=IO, character_offset=892}]'

def conv(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None if s == '' else s

dct = [ 
  { k: conv(v) for k,v in d.items() }
  for d in json.loads(
    re.sub(
      '([^\s[{^=]+)=([^,}]*)([,}\]])',
      '"\\1":"\\2"\\3',
      body
    )
  )
]
```

---

###### Both solutions yield:

```py
# dct
[
  {
    'location_type': 1,
    'location_fullname': 'Papua New Guinea',
    'location_countrycode': 'PP',
    'location_adm1code': 'PP',
    'location_adm2code': None,
    'location_latitude': -6,
    'location_longitude': 147,
    'location_featureid': 'PP',
    'character_offset': 16
  },
  {
    'location_type': 1,
    'location_fullname': 'Papua New Guinea',
    'location_countrycode': 'PP',
    'location_adm1code': 'PP',
    'location_adm2code': None,
    'location_latitude': -6,
    'location_longitude': 147,
    'location_featureid': 'PP',
    'character_offset': 290},
  {
    'location_type': 1,
    'location_fullname': 'Indonesia',
    'location_countrycode': 'ID',
    'location_adm1code': 'ID',
    'location_adm2code': None,
    'location_latitude': -5,
    'location_longitude': 120,
    'location_featureid': 'ID',
    'character_offset': 676
  },
  {
    'location_type': 1,
    'location_fullname': 'North Korea',
    'location_countrycode': 'KN',
    'location_adm1code': 'KN',
    'location_adm2code': None,
    'location_latitude': 40,
    'location_longitude': 127,
    'location_featureid': 'KN',
    'character_offset': 748
  },
  {
    'location_type': 1,
    'location_fullname': 'British Indian Ocean Territory',
    'location_countrycode': 'IO',
    'location_adm1code': 'IO',
    'location_adm2code': None,
    'location_latitude': -6,
    'location_longitude': 71.5,
    'location_featureid': 'IO', 'character_offset': 892
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would process what `yaml` is giving you since it is *almost* there:

```
import yaml 

ex='''
[{location_type=1, location_fullname=Papua New Guinea, location_countrycode=PP, location_adm1code=PP, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=147, location_featureid=PP, character_offset=16}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=Papua New Guinea, location_countrycode=PP, location_adm1code=PP, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=147, location_featureid=PP, character_offset=290}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=Indonesia, location_countrycode=ID, location_adm1code=ID, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-5, location_longitude=120, location_featureid=ID, character_offset=676}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=North Korea, location_countrycode=KN, location_adm1code=KN, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=40, location_longitude=127, location_featureid=KN, character_offset=748}, {location_type=1, location_fullname=British Indian Ocean Territory, location_countrycode=IO, location_adm1code=IO, location_adm2code=, location_latitude=-6, location_longitude=71.5, location_featureid=IO, character_offset=892}]'''

def conv(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        pass 
        
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s
        

res=[{x:conv(y) for x,y in map(lambda s: s.split('='), di)} 
       for di in yaml.load(ex, Loader=yaml.CLoader)]

>>> res
[{'location_type': 1, 'location_fullname': 'Papua New Guinea', 'location_countrycode': 'PP', 'location_adm1code': 'PP', 'location_adm2code': '', 'location_latitude': -6, 'location_longitude': 147, 'location_featureid': 'PP', 'character_offset': 16}, {'location_type': 1, 'location_fullname': 'Papua New Guinea', 'location_countrycode': 'PP', 'location_adm1code': 'PP', 'location_adm2code': '', 'location_latitude': -6, 'location_longitude': 147, 'location_featureid': 'PP', 'character_offset': 290}, {'location_type': 1, 'location_fullname': 'Indonesia', 'location_countrycode': 'ID', 'location_adm1code': 'ID', 'location_adm2code': '', 'location_latitude': -5, 'location_longitude': 120, 'location_featureid': 'ID', 'character_offset': 676}, {'location_type': 1, 'location_fullname': 'North Korea', 'location_countrycode': 'KN', 'location_adm1code': 'KN', 'location_adm2code': '', 'location_latitude': 40, 'location_longitude': 127, 'location_featureid': 'KN', 'character_offset': 748}, {'location_type': 1, 'location_fullname': 'British Indian Ocean Territory', 'location_countrycode': 'IO', 'location_adm1code': 'IO', 'location_adm2code': '', 'location_latitude': -6, 'location_longitude': 71.5, 'location_featureid': 'IO', 'character_offset': 892}]
```